# Can devices connected to a Wi-Fi router communicate with devices connected to an associated Wi-Fi repeater?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, repeater

If I connect a Wi-Fi repeater to my existing network, can devices connected to the original router connect to devices connected to the repeater?

For example, if my laptop is on the router, can I see a printer on the repeater network. I’m using Windows mainly, but I also use Linux from time to time. Ubuntu is the most usual distro I use. The kind of repeater that I would be using would be a wireless set up. It would not be connected to the original router through Ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Yes—the repeater merely extends the network, acting as a network switch.

- The repeater takes a WiFi signal from your access point and transmits a new signal to extend the network. It does not create a separate subnet—it only acts as a wireless [network switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch). As such, any devices connected to the repeater are part of the same network and devices on the main router can communicate with devices on the repeater.

Comment: So if I were to go the cheap route and use a regular router that I already have as a repeater, would it work the same way? Or should I go with the repeater?

Comment: It would work the same way. The router is a layer 3 device (and may operate on higher layers), but most can act as a layer 2 switch/bridge just like a repeater, disregarding higher layers of the OSI stack.

Answer (score 0):

A Wi-Fi repeater extends the reach of the current network by repeating the Wi-Fi signals. So if they can see devices on the network while attached to the router, they should be able to also see it while attached to the repeater.